# What are light years? like you know how people measure some things in light years? what is light years

Tags: speed-of-light, definition, units, metrology, length

so basically you know how scientists measure how far things are but in space and they measure in light years well what are light years and how long are light years?

Answer (score 1):

A light year is the distance that light travels in a year.  So it is a measure of distance, not time.  Light travels about 300,000 kilometers in one second, or about 9.46 trillion kilometers in one year.   It's a heck of a long way, but that just shows you how big space is that we need to measure things in light years.

Answer (score 1):

One [light-year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-year) (ly) is the distance light travels in one [Julian year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_year_(astronomy)) ($\text{a}_j$). The [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) is defined to be

$$
c = 299792458 \text{ m/s}
$$
A Julian year is defined by
$$
1 \text{ a}_j = 365.25 \text{ day} = 365.25 \text{ days} \times 86400 \text{ s/day} = 31557600 \text{ s}
$$

Where one day is defined as
$$
1 \text{ day} = 86400 \text{ s}
$$
So one light year is

$$
1 \text{ ly} = c \times 1 \text{ a}_j = 9.4607304725808 \times 10^{15} \text{ m} = 9.4607304725808\times 10^{12} \text{ km}
$$

Note that because of how the speed of light and other units above are defined all of the expressions are **exact** with no uncertainty.

The mile is defined by
$$
1 \text{ mi} = 1609.344 \text{ m}
$$

so

$$
1 \text{ ly} = 5.878625373183607\ldots\times 10^{12} \text{ mi}
$$

The decimal expression for one light year in units of miles does not terminate because of the particular division that it results from.

Let me know if I made a mistake somewhere.